None Type object is not subscriptable Kivy
I am creating an app which is just an TOTP authenticator, but for some reason, my app started throwing an error:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I tried to change all spaces to tabs, but it didn't work.
And here's the full error, and code.
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /storage/emulated/0/auther/.kivy/logs/kivy_24-08-12_94.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.4 (main, Sep 30 2023, 10:54:38) [GCC 11.4.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.2.0, git-Unknown, 2024-08-12 (installed at "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivymd/__init__.py")
[WARNING] [KivyMD      ] Version 1.2.0 is deprecated and is no longer supported. Use KivyMD version 2.0.0 from the master branch (pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip)
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r20p0-01rel0.3c1c24cb7710121ad59f6bdaee909f9f'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ARM'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mali-G52 MC2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/storage/emulated/0/auther/main.py", line 85, in <module>
     auther().run() 
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 925, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/storage/emulated/0/auther/main.py", line 37, in build
     return Builder.load_string("""
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 372, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 483, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 593, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 696, in parse_level
     _objects, _lines = self.parse_level(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 756, in parse_level
     if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

And code:
import hmac


import base64


import struct
import hashlib
import time
import plyer

import pickle


def get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no):
    key = base64.b32decode(secret, True)
    msg = struct.pack(">Q", intervals_no)
    h = hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    o = h[19] & 15
    h = (struct.unpack(">I", h[o:o+4])[0] & 0x7fffffff) % 1000000
    return h
 
from kivymd.app import MDApp 

from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
 
class auther(MDApp):  
    def build(self): 
        return Builder.load_string("""
<DrawerClickableItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem>
    focus_color: "#e7e4c0"
    text_color: "#4a4939"
    icon_color: "#4a4939"
    ripple_color: "#c5bdd2"
    selected_color: "#0c6c4d"


<DrawerLabelItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem>
    text_color: "#4a4939"
    icon_color: "#4a4939"
    focus_behavior: False
    selected_color: "#4a4939"
    _no_ripple_effect: True
MDBoxLayout: 
    orientation: "vertical"
    pos: 0,0
    size_hint: 1,1
    spacing: "12dp"
    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "MDTopAppBar"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
    MDScreenManager:
        MDScreen:
            MDScrollView:
                MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                    text: "Hello!"
                    icon: "key"
                    size_hint: 1,0.1
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
            radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)
            MDNavigationDrawerMenu:
                MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
                    title: "Auther"
                    title_color: "#4a4939"
                    text: "Built by simpleuserdontwatch ;)"
                    spacing: "4dp"
                    padding: "12dp", 0, 0, "56dp"

                DrawerClickableItem:
                    icon: "settings"
                    text_right_color: "#4a4939"
                    text: "Settings"
""") 
 
auther().run() 


It means current_property is None and so you can't use a subscript like [:3] on that value. There's way too much code here for us to debug why that is happening. Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Is that the whole traceback? It doesn't show where you're calling the function in your application.

I just added the whole traceback, hope that helps

You have incorrect indentation in your kivy string:
MDNavigationDrawer:
    id: nav_drawer
        radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)
        MDNavigationDrawerMenu:
            MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
                title: "Auther"
                title_color: "#4a4939"
                text: "Built by simpleuserdontwatch ;)"
                spacing: "4dp"
                padding: "12dp", 0, 0, "56dp"

            DrawerClickableItem:
                icon: "settings"
                text_right_color: "#4a4939"
                text: "Settings"

should be:
MDNavigationDrawer:
    id: nav_drawer
    radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)
    MDNavigationDrawerMenu:
        MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
            title: "Auther"
            title_color: "#4a4939"
            text: "Built by simpleuserdontwatch ;)"
            spacing: "4dp"
            padding: "12dp", 0, 0, "56dp"

        DrawerClickableItem:
            icon: "settings"
            text_right_color: "#4a4939"
            text: "Settings"

